# How can I create a train data file like [text, author] for an NLP task

Tags: python, nlp

In NLP task, I have some text files for some authors. Data are in folders like this:

```
  |author1|
     |text_file1|
     |text_file2|
     ...
  |author2|
     |text_file1|
     |text_file2|
     ...
  ...
```

I want to loop through these folders and create a train and validation datasets like the following. Validation data contains two random files from each author

```
id  text                                                author
0   This process, however, afforded me no means of...   author1
1   It never once occurred to me that the fumbling...   author1
.   ...
.   In his left hand was a gold snuff box, from wh...   author2
.   ...
```

What is the best approach for creating these datasets?

I tried something like this:

```
train = []
val = []
for folder_name in folders:
    file_path = data_path +'/' + folder_name
    files = os.listdir(file_path)

    v1 = np.random.randint(0, len(files))
    v2 = np.random.randint(0, len(files))
    for i, fn in enumerate(files):
      fn = file_path + '/' + fn    
      f = open(fn)
      text = f.read()
      # preprocessing text
      if i == v1 or i == v2:
        val.append(text)
      else:
        train.append(text)
      f.close()
```

However, my problem is to associate the `folder_name` to each text and save the whole data in the format I described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary to dump each row in it and in the end convert it intoa Dataframe.

```
 train = []
    val = []
    for folder_name in folders:
        file_path = data_path +'/' + folder_name
        files = os.listdir(file_path)

        v1 = np.random.randint(0, len(files))
        v2 = np.random.randint(0, len(files))
        for i, fn in enumerate(files):
            dict = {}
          fn = file_path + '/' + fn
          f = open(fn)
          text = f.read()
          # preprocessing text
          dict['author'] = folder_name
          dict['text'] = text
          if i == v1 or i == v2:
            val.append(dict)
          else:
            train.append(dict)

        df = pd.DataFrame(val)
        f.close()
```

Comment: Please tick this as an answer if it suffices.. :)